# Merging different values based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have made an excel, which gives me an overview of certain jobs that people are working on. I want excel to make analysis based on multiple criteria, which are present.

**The Problem**: Look at the following excel sheet.

[image]

In the excel image, you can see that the data is divided into three columns. The colour, the painter responsible for the coloring and number of jobs he has. I want to make a table, such as shown in the following figure.

[image]

The way I am trying to make merge the data is, so that excel could show me:

a) Total number of jobs a painter has. I have been succesful in that, because I use the code:

=IF(SUM.IF($B$16:$B$39;G15;$C$16:$C$39)=0;"";SUM.IF($B$16:$B$39;G15;$C$16:$C$39))

(got plenty help from an user from here). By using this, it give me a product of jobs for each painter, which is nice

b) In the second column, I want sum of jobs of *each* paint for a specific painter. So that it shows that John has 8 jobs with Black Paint, and 1 job with blue paint. Hence making a total of 9 jobs.

Any idea on how it could be possible. Because the method I am using now is that I manually look for each job and number of jobs, by filtering the data  based on painter. But it takes a lot of time and is not very efficient. Any clue/hint/help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use a pivot table?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it failed. Its because the above is a simple example, which I have made in order to get suggestion. In reality, the data is a bit a more complicated. I have also numbers in as Painters. Therefore, if I do a Pivot Table, then it also gives the sum of those numbers with the sum of jobs. Plus there are merged cells involved in the headings, therefore it also messes up when applying that table.

Comment: To continue with JvdV's suggestion, please consider reformatting your data so that a pivot table will work. As far as summing painter's numbers, I think you need the painter's name/number field in columns or rows section, not the values section.

Comment: You may be able to use sumifs() formulas to do your task if you create a table and manually add your row and column headers. But I suspect your merge fields will cause problems with this approach too.

Comment: @gns100, thanks for the suggestions. I have reformatted the data so that the pivot table now works.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for your suggestion and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Total Jobs you can try to use SUM function directly in Table:

[image]

For each color total value you can try to use SUMPRODUCT function:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is truly helpful becaus now I can just apply this a whole lot of data and let it calculate as I update the cells. Thank you very much!